# How to test properties of a nested list object in Groovy test with spoc

Tags: groovy, collections, spock

I am writing a groovy test. My response object should like this:

```
[ school: new School( 
id: "School1", 
name: "School1", 
courses: [ 
new Course(id: "Course1", name: "Course1"),
new Course(id: "Course2", name: "Course2")])]
```

Below is my test:

```
def "should update the name of the school and course as per their id"() {

given:

def request = requestObject

when:

def response = myService.update(requestObject)

then: "name of the school should be equal to its id"
result.collect {
        it.name == it.id
}.every { it }

and: "name of each course should be equal to its id"
//Need help

}
```

I can't think of how to write the 'and' part in my test as its a nested collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use Groovy power assert here in order to get descriptive error messages in case of mismatches:

```
then: "name of the school should be equal to its id"
result.each {
    assert it.name == it.id
}

and: "name of each course should be equal to its id"
result*.courses*.each {
    assert it.name == it.id
}
```

`*.` is [the Groovy spread operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator)

However, if you want to know which school has mismatched courses then it will be a bit more verbose in the `and:` section

Answer (score 0):

I think this can assert it:

```
result.every { it.courses.every { course => course.id == course.name }
```

In each school, every course name must equal its course id.